# Problema con bucle for en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo una operación en una variable llamada $s,

```
$sf= ($s - ($a+ $t))
```

las variables $s, $ay $t son números fijos en una primera iteración, luego de esto, la variable $sf pasa a ser el resultado de la variable $sf

```
$s= $row['s'];
$a= $row['a'];
$t= $row['t'];

$sf= ($s - ($a+ $t))
```

Intenté algo como esto:

```
            for ($i=0; $i < 10; ) { 
                $sf= ($s- ($a+ $t));
                $r= ROUND($sf);?>
                <td><?php echo $r?></td>
            <?php  $i++;

                $sf2= ($r- ($a+ $t));
                $r2= ROUND($sf2);?>
                <td><?php  echo $r?></td>
           <?php } ?>
```

Intente crear otra variable con la nueva variable $r como el saldo para la operacion, pero no funciona lo que quiero.

para propositos de explicar mejor, en teoría lo que quiero lograr es algo como esto:

```
                for ($i=0; $i < 10; ) { 
                $sp= ($s- ($a+ $t));
                $sf = ROUND($sp);?>
                <td><?php  echo $sf ?></td>
            <?php  $i++;

                $sp2= ($s - ($a+ $t));
                $s2 = ROUND($saldo_proyectado2);?>
                <td><?php  echo $s2 ?></td>
                <?php  $i++;

                $sp3= ($s2 - ($a+ $t));
                $s3 = ROUND($sp3);?>
                <td><?php  echo $s3 ?></td>
                <?php  $i++;

                $saldo_proyectado4 = ($s3 - ($a+ $t));
                $s4 = ROUND($sp4);?>
                <td><?php  echo $s4 ?></td>
                <?php  $i++;

                $saldo_proyectado5 = ($s4 - ($a+ $t));
                $s5 = ROUND($sp5);?>
                <td><?php  echo $s5 ?></td>
           <?php } ?>
```

O este excel:

Para el día 22/09/2021
la casilla en amarillo es el numero inicial.
El saldo proy es el campo calculado tomando la casilla de amarillo, restando el ay sumando el t.
luego para el día 23/09/2021
el saldo será el saldo proy del dia anterior, y el saldo pro será de nuevo el campo calculado tomando en cuenta estos valores..

ALGUNA SOLUCIÓN??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitarías es hacer algo como esto. Luego  el hacer que luzca como una tabla es tema de maquetación, pero lo que es la lógica debería de ser similar a esta:

**PHP**

```
<?php

//Se declaran las variables, junto al valor que tendrán inicialmente.
$saldo = 100;
$adu = 5.5;
$transito = 0;

// Se hace un bucle para que el proceso se ejecute las veces que necesitemos.
// Yo puse que hasta 4 veces porque es el número de días que muestras en tu ejemplo
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    echo $saldo . '<br>';
    echo $adu . '<br>';
    echo $transito . '<br>';
    
    //Se calcula y se imprime el saldo final
    $saldo_final = $saldo - ($adu + $transito);
    echo $saldo_final;
    
    // Haces que saldo pase a valer lo mismo que saldo final para que en la siguiente
    // iteración del bucle sea el valor del que partir
    $saldo = $saldo_final;
    
    echo '<hr>';
}

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
100
5.5
0
94.5
----------------
94.5
5.5
0
89
----------------
89
5.5
0
83.5
----------------
83.5
5.5
0
78
----------------
```